# problem to make a Dynamic Associative Array in the shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, dictionary

i have problem to make a dictionary inside a array in shell script

so for example with some commands i  have two column

```
record       zone                     

test07      cname.lan                
test07-ext  ca.us               
test07-t    ca.us               
test07      ca.net              
test-t      ca.net    

so i want to have  ass_array=([[test07]="cname.lan" [test07-ext]="ca.us" [test07-t]="ca.us".....
```

I use this code but i but it doesn't work.

```
rec_array=($(somecommand))  ## check and it has correct value
zone_array=($(somecommand))  ##check and it has correct value
declare -A ass_array

for(( i=0;i<= "${#rec_array[@]}";i+=1  ));

     do
             key="${rec_array[$i]}"
             val="${zone_array[$i]}"

             ass_array["$key"]+="$val"
done
```

Comment: There are several problems in your bash script. Try running it through https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it has not logic error just some replacement recommended  to get more refinement but it was not related to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in the exit condition of your for loop; you are iterating past the end of the array.